# Python - Mac - renamed file is created at the same level with the folder that was containing it

Tags: python

I am trying to rename a file in a specific path, but it moves the file at the same level with the folder that was containing it before being renamed.

```
import os
path_to_file = "/Users/Me/file.txt" #NOTE that in my code, file name will be randomly generated 
path_before_file, file_name = os.path.split(path_to_file) # I need file_name from here, which is the file name without the rest of the path: "file.txt"
renamed_file = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] + '_renamed' + os.path.splitext(file_name)[1] #This is how renamed file I want to look "file_renamed.txt"
renamed_file_path = os.path.join(path_to_file, renamed_file) #"/Users/Me/file_renamed.txt"
os.rename(path_to_file, renamed_file_path)
```

After renaming, "/Users/Me/file.txt" becomes "/Users/file.txt"

Comment: where are you trying to move it?

Comment: With the code you show, the filename is `"/Users/Me/file.txt/file_renamed.txt"` because `os.path.join(path_to_file, renamed_file)` should be `os.path.join(path_before_file, renamed_file)`. Check there is no other errors.

Comment: don't you want `renamed_file_path = os.path.join(path_before_file, renamed_file)`?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake here when editing the code. That is correct, I am using "renamed_file_path = os.path.join(path_before_file, renamed_file) #"/Users/Me/file_renamed.txt""

Comment: apart from that mistake, your code works fine for me, I just tried it. So, I don't know why it is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
renamed_file_path = os.path.join(path_to_file, renamed_file) #"/Users/Me/file_renamed.txt"
```

Above line has a bug. Above line should be as below

```
renamed_file_path = os.path.join(path_before_file, renamed_file) #"/Users/Me/file_renamed.txt"
```

Comment: It was a mistake in the code I wrote here. I am actually using "renamed_file_path = os.path.join(path_before_file, renamed_file)"

Comment: @mhd is your problem solved now? Is there anything that I can help? Do you want the file to move to upper folder in hierarchy?

Comment: unfortunately it's not solved yet. On my local machine I am using renamed_file_path = os.path.join(path_before_file, renamed_file). The bug you described was only in the code that I pasted here on Stack. I don't want the file to be moved anywhere, just trying to rename it. "Users/Me/file.txt" to be renamed to "Users/Me/file_renamed.txt"

Comment: @mhd can you print path_before_file before you do os.path.join and also print remaned_file_path after you do os.path.join?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem. path_before_file was something like "Users/Me"(without slash at the end). If I do:

```
renamed_file_path = os.path.join(path_before_file + '/' + renamed_file)
```

or

```
renamed_file_path = path_before_file + '/' + renamed_file
```

it works. But AFAIK, you wouldn't need this when working with os.path.join()

This is the code that works:

```
import os
path_to_file = "/Users/Me/file.txt"
path_before_file, file_name = os.path.split(path_to_file) 
renamed_file = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] + '_renamed' +   os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]
renamed_file_path = path_before_file + '/' + renamed_file
os.rename(path_to_file, renamed_file_path)
```